# Can I style text in localized Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am using `intl` package (by using `flutter_localizations`) and I was wondering how one would go about styling portions of localized text.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "Your name is {name}",
  "@name": {
    "placeholders": {
       "name": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
  class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String _name = 'User';
  // ... some Flutter widget
  Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.name(_name),
```

Expectation:

> Your name is **User**

Is there a recommended approach to solve this? I have found [`styled_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/styled_text) package but if I could avoid using 3rd party lib, I would prefer it.

**I want to avoid splitting text into multiple items** as that would not work because different languages might require different ordering and I do not want to deal with that inside widgets by detecting language programmatically.